# Search API- SolR - Processing solr response in drupal

Tags: search

I'm currently trying to find a function that process SolR response to a query that is sent with the `search` method of `SearchApiSolrConnection` class.

Here is how the search is done:

```
  $values = $_GET['search'];
  $options = variable_get('MY_OPTIONS');
  $solr_connection = new SearchApiSolrConnection($options);
  $q_request = FUNCTION_PROCESSING_REQUEST($values);
  $params = array(
    'q' => $q_request,
    'start' => 0,
    'rows' => 10000,
    'fq' => array(
      ''
    ),
    'fl' => '*,score'
  );
  $result = $solr_connection->search(null, $params);
```

The SolR core indexes content from SolR and other databases. I wondered if there was a functionality that processes the response to a more Drupal friendly variable (a renderable array or an key-value array). Today I have variables that look like : `im_node$field_my_field`.

Is it possible to transform this variables into ones that are like `node:field_my_field` instead of `im_node$field_my_field`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `$solr_connection->extractResults($query, $result);` help?

Comment: Thanks Clib, I've work it out using the code in `extractResults` method. A meta question : Is it preferable that I share the solution ?